# firestore: Is there a way to perform or where query operation on collection?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Scenario**

**Given** I am a tutor

**When** I type comma separated list of search terms

e.g math,accounting

**Then Expected**

I should be able to see different documents having map field key term set to true

**Then Actual**

I get empty result

**When** I type comma separate terms that relates to the same document

I get the actual result

**Question**

Is there or Operation for cloud firestore.

Kindly find below code snippet and screenshots:

```dart
Future<void> search(List<String> keywords) async {
    var docs = coursesRef.where('isDraft', isEqualTo: false);

    keywords.forEach((word) {
      String term = word.trim().toLowerCase();
      print("$term\n");
      docs = docs.where('searchTerms.$term', isEqualTo: true);
    });

    QuerySnapshot query = await docs.getDocuments();

    courses = [];
    query.documents.forEach((doc) {
      Course course = Course.fromDoc(doc);
      courses.add(course);
    });

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**Below screen shot for sample `Map<String, bool>`**

[image]

Comment: There is no logical OR.  You'll need to perform multiple queries and combine the results in the app.